# How to change the tray icon with Java?

Tags: java, system-tray, trayicon, systray

I need to change the tray icon, so that it would notify users about the number of unread messages.

How to do this with Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`SystemTray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java 6 then his article covers what you need I believe.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

It has a simple example file that shows how to set the sytemtray icon. It also covers some of the usueful methods.

Specifically `TrayIcon.setImage()`

Answer (score 1):

For versions of Java earlier than 6, I've used JTray, a commercial library.  It's OK.  Pretty similar to the Java 6 class.